# 404 Not Found when trying to open route inside app folder in python flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have my project folder structure like below:

```
Project/
   app/
      templates/
        base.html
        index.html
      user/
        __init__.py
        routes.py
   venv/
   Hello.py
```

`Hello.py` is file that used to initialize my project, so that I can open another route from there, in case from `app/user/routes.py`. So, I have my `Hello.py` code like below:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, redirect,url_for
from app import app 
from app.user.routes import *

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True 
    app.run()
    app.run(debug = True)
```

And in `app/user/routes.py` I defined one route function `/user` as below:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

@app.route('/user')
def get_user():
    user = {'username':'Migual'}
    posts = [
        {
            'author': {'username':'John'},
            'body':'Beautiful day in Portland!'
        },
        {
            'author': {'username':'Susan'},
            'body':'The Avengers movie was so cool!'
        }

    ]
    return render_template('index.html',title='Home',user=user,posts=posts);
```

However, I run `$ python Hello.py`, it works as normal, but in browser, when I navigate `http://127.0.0.1:5000/user`, I got `404 Not Found` like this:

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you
>   entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Any clue how can I open route `/user` defined in `routes.py`? Thanks.

Comment: What is in `app/__init__.py`?

Comment: `app/__init__.py` is just an empty file that used for python to know this directory is used as package, so I can import it like `import app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you Hello.Py as following:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, redirect,url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
from app.user.routes import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Change your routes.py as following:

```
from flask import render_template
from Hello import app

@app.route('/user')
def get_user():
    user = {'username':'Migual'}
    posts = [
        {
            'author': {'username':'John'},
            'body':'Beautiful day in Portland!'
        },
        {
            'author': {'username':'Susan'},
            'body':'The Avengers movie was so cool!'
        }

    ]
   return render_template('index.html',title='Home',user=user,posts=posts)
```

Comment: You may need to specify absolute path for  Hello.py in routes.py or put the both files in same folder and then Hellp.py  just `from routes import *

Comment: I access route url '/user` but I got `TemplateNotFound: index.html`. The reason I separate both files above because I will have many different modules I will created one of them is `user` module here. So I don't want put them all in just one file instead make them in their own folder and file. Thanks.

Comment: U can try the code above, I have tested, this works fine. Please make sure you have index.html in your templates folder

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it is inside `app/templates/` already, maybe `/templates/` has not been known yet, as I tried another file like `index1.html` also not found. Thanks

Comment: and where is your Hello.py, move the templates at same  level as Hello.py

Comment: `Hello.py` is at root directory `Project/Hello.py`. So, I have moved folder template to the root directory as well `Project/templates/index.html` the same level with `Hello.py`, and it works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Very crude programming. You use `Hello.py` as main and as module. In main you create `app` but ignore it, and in `Hello` you create `app` and include it into main via `routes`. Don't do such things. Look at my solution, plase.

Comment: I just tried to solve the probelm OP was facing not the architect of the whole application

Comment: You introduced new architectural problems.

Comment: Yes, i looked at yours it looks more cleaner approach :)

Answer (score 1):

You create a new `app` in `hello.py` and don't use the `app` imported from `app` in `app.user.routes`.

Your `hello.py` should look like this:

```
from app import app 
import app.user.routes # just to define the routes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and a `app/__init__.py` should look like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Comment: what you meant by `create a new app in hello.py` could you show folder structure? I run above script and error message `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Hello.py", line 5, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'`

Comment: So, you have to show your folder structure. You have a package `app`, but you have also a module `app`? Which you didn't show, yet?

Comment: I did not have module `app`, `app` is just folder as a package container other module such as `user` in this case. Thanks

Comment: So, how does `app` appear in `app.user.routes`?